# Haskell req package: how to use withReqManager to reuse connection for many requests to the same host?

Tags: haskell, https, req, haskell-req

I would like to reuse a HTTPS connection for many requests to keep latency as low as possible for every request to the same host. Using the haskell package req, if I send too many requests in a short period of time then it seems I might be reaching a connection limit for the `Manager` and a new connection is started, showing higher latency. I can't change the connection limit in the req package for the `Manager` to fix this. Instead the package documentation recommends to use `withReqManager` to reuse connections. But i cant comprehend how to use this function. Could someone explain to me how to use it to always reuse a connection for an explicit series of requests, please?

Another example where the connection is not reused is when too much time passes between requests to the same host. When i delay a request for 5 seconds the connection is reused but if i delay for 60 seconds it is not reused. If someone could provide an example using `withReqManger` to reuse the connection for every time i run `ttst` I'd really appreciate it.

```
lttest :: IO ()
lttest = do ttst
            threadDelay 5000000
            ttst
            threadDelay 60000000
            ttst 
       where ttst = do metm <- getCurrentTime
                       runReq defaultHttpConfig { httpConfigCheckResponse = \_ _ _ -> Nothing } $ do
                        v <- req GET (https "ifconfig.me") (NoReqBody) lbsResponse mempty
                        liftIO $ print (responseBody v :: Data.ByteString.Lazy.ByteString) 
                       metm2 <- getCurrentTime
                       print (diffUTCTime metm2 metm)
```

Edit: I think i may have found a way to ensure that the connection is reused, but it requires a small hack and not using the req package. As @WillemVanOnsem commented, the server will likely close the connection after some time. So I have to send a dummy request every few seconds to the same host to keep the connection alive. But then I still need to find a way to keep the connection alive from having many requests being sent over a small period. The wreq package has a module called Network.Wreq.Session. This module allows you to initialize a `Session` and do all of your requests on the same connection by passing the same `Session` to each request. So far this seems to be working. An important note is that your dummy request or any other request for that matter using the same `Session` should not occur at the same time. If they ever do occur at the same time, the connection wont be reused that time.

Comment: Likely the connection will be closed at the server's end after waiting for a certain amount of time.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem okay i can send a dummy request every few seconds to keep the server from doing that. But even then i still have the issue where if I send many requests, every second instead of every 10 seconds for example, that the connection is not always reused. Do you have any advice to address that?